# Android app to import multiple offline calendars from .ics file

Tags: android, offline, calendar

Using Business Calendar 2 app, I exported 4 offline calendars into an `.ics` file.  (I then deleted all calendar events within the calendar itself to fix a bug.)

Afterwards. I tried to use the same Business Calendar 2 app (no longer recommended!) to import that `.ics` file.  When it imported the file, it merged all 4 calendars into a single calendar!  Ugh!  :-(

Does anyone know of an Android (KitKat) app that will import an `.ics` file that contains multiple calendars into multiple **offline** calendars?

*Technical details:*

- The calendar name for each event within the `.ics` file is specified as `ORGANIZER:CN=[calname]`, where `[calname]` is replaced with the name of the appropriate calendar.
- Each event contains `X-WR-CALNAME:[calname]`

Comment: Not sure if my first recommendation on your other question ([Android app to backup one or more offline calendars](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23497/185)) might help here (I've not much experience in that sector – none with such a combined `.ics`, I always used separate ones for each calendar).