# Android app to backup one or more offline calendars

Tags: android, offline, backup, calendar

Can anyone recommend an Android (KitKat compatible) app to backup one or more ***offline*** calendars?  It needs to be able to restore them as well.

I would prefer gratis, but am open to all options.

I would prefer backups be in `.ics` format, but am open to **all** options, including `.csv` format.

*Note that Business Calendar and Business Calendar 2 have this functionality, but I have not had complete success performing a round-trip (export followed by import) of the data with either version of that app.*

Comment: Have not tried that myself, but my app list [Backup calendars](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_135) lists two possible candidates: [Calendar ICS adapter](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.k3b.android.calendar.ics.adapter) (open source, at F-Droid) and [ICAL Import/Export](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.drlue.icalimportexport) (free/paid) both offer this. The former directly to `.ics` files, the latter via DAV or email. I'd suggest give the first a try.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  I just tried *Calendar ICS adapter*.  It looks like you have to import/export one event at a time!  So, unfortunately, that won't work.

Comment: Oh wow, I must have missed that part. Must ask the dev to rename the app to *Event* ICS adapter, if it just works on single events :( Sorry for that! Remains the free version of the other, and either DAV or mail the `.ics` to yourself.

Comment: Another candidat: [Calendar Processor](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marhinri.calendarprocessor.free). [CalendarSync](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icalparse.free) also claims to be capable. And there's my list of [Calendar Tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general#group_58) with some more.